# How to get the result of stored procedure with parameter and use for Crystal Report in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, crystal-reports

My IDE is MS Visual Studio 2008.

I just want to ask how can I get the result of a store procedure from MS Access using VB.Net and use the result in a Crystal Report.

I have a Windows Application Project that requires this function.

Thanks in advance for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the code from the previous answer on executing a stored procedure, you can create a dataset and then pass this dataset to Crystal Reports.

In order to design the report in Crystal Reports, you should take the following steps (the details for each step can easily be found in the Visual Studio help or online):

1) Add a connection to the access database in server explorer.

2) Create a new DataSet for the stored procedure (query) within visual studio. We'll assume that this is called DataSet1.

3) Create your Crystal Report and have it use this new DataSet. We'll assume that this report is called CyrstalReport1.

4) Add a CrystalReportViewer to your form that you are displaying the reports on. We'll assume the viewer is called CrystalReportViewer1.

5) Add the following code to your form to execute the query, fill the dataset, and load the crystal report with the dataset.

```
Dim oReport As New CrystalReport1
Dim dsDataSet as New DataSet1

Using conn As New OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\myaccess.mdb"
    conn.Open()
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "NameOfTheQuery"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        ' Note: You can also use CommandType.TableDirect
        cmd.Connection = conn

        Using oAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter
            oAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
            oAdapter.Fill(dsData)

            ' Set the data source for the report to the new dataset
            oReport.SetDataSource(dsDataSet)
            ' Set the report into the viewer
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oReport
        End Using

        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```